# How to merge data with in the file using any too, command or regex

Tags: regex

I have file that contains like below

```
Emploee #1,
Employee name

Emploee #2,
Employee name

Emploee #3,
Employee name
```

And i wanted data in this forma

```
Emploee #1,Employee name
Emploee #2,Employee name
Emploee #1,Employee name
```

I have 100,000 records. Manual work will take long time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of file type contains the data? What language are you trying to use for regex?

Comment: So you simply want to remove the line breaks and put all on one line? And remove the space after each comma?

Comment: I don't want all in one line but each employee# and name in each line

Comment: Its .txt fie. I just mentioned whether regex can solve this easily

Comment: You need to use proper formatting in your question to show the exact format you need. I've made the necessary edit, which is currently pending.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the raw formatting of your question, this Python script should perform the conversion:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as inFile, \
     open('output.txt', 'w') as outFile:
  lines = inFile.read().splitlines()
  for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
    number = lines[i]
    name = lines[i+1]
    outFile.write(number + name + '\n')
```

It assumes that the input file always has three lines per employee, with the number first, then the name, then an empty line (except for the very last entry).

Answer (score 0):

If in 'this' format means make it display in on line then there is C# solution:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("inputFile");
  var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("outputFile");

  foreach (string s in arr)
    file.Write($"{s} ");

  file.Close();
}
```

Output:

```
Emploee #1, Employee name  Emploee #2, Employee name  Emploee #3, Employee name
```

Comment: Hi Seb.. each employee details in different line.

Comment: Would appreciate a proper example of the output you need then, will be much easier. And I assume the data in your has this structure:
Emploee #1, Employee name

Emploee #2, Employee name
Emploee #3, Employee name